# Firebase .info/connected showing 'CONNECTED' when offline

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have this code on my web app:

```
const connectedRef = firebase.database().ref('.info/connected')
connectedRef.on('value', function(snap) {
  if (snap.val() === true) {
    console.log('CONNECT')
    connected = true
  } else {
    console.log('DISCONNECT')
    connected = false
  }
})
```

When I go offline using the "offline" checkbox in the Developer tools, I expect to see a single `DISCONNECT` message. What I see instead is:

```
-- app starts

DISCONNECT
CONNECT

-- here I go "Offline"

DISCONNECT
CONNECT -- What ?
```

I don't undestand why I see my application getting immediately "connected" again while I'm still offline. Bug? Or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: What happens when you make a phone go offline (as apposed to checking offline in the developer tools)?